# data-show-faces="false" not being handled in facebook like button HTML5 version

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

The data-show-faces flag is set to false but once facebook like is clicked it still shows the text box with the profile pic on it.. this is happening recently is the flag still working?!

Comment: Does the same behavior exist on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ?

Comment: YES the same behavior shows up on the page even with the show_faces option unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the answer is YES,

This is how!

Use the html5 version of like button and add this to the css

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely the 'flyout' pane as its known is not related to the `data-show-faces` attr, which is concerned with the display of profile pictures below the like button.

This flyout cannot in the html5 version (afaik, dont think its used in the iframe one) be disabled but you can override it in css to not display if thats what you're looking todo:

```
.connect_comment_widget { display:none; }
```

Comment: can it be disabled in the xfbml version without a css override?

Comment: is there something about the placement of the override that I need to know?.. currently its not kicking in.. for html5

Comment: I've provided my code above.. can u pl tell me where exactly do I call the overriden class to turn off the flyout pane..

Comment: the ids and classes of propriety fb content is appended with random numbers each time they are rendered.. so it is not possible to use the id and override the class.. I dont think you can override fb css if thats the case